# Angle of three independently chosen points on a cricle

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory

If a,b,c are three points on a circle (viewed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not disc) chosen independently and uniformly,and p(x) is the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle formed by the points abc is greater than x$\pi$?

---

So far what I've gotten:

Considering the problem in polar coordinates, let $>0$ and let $(0,r)$ $(\phi,r)$ and $(\psi,r)$ be the coordinates of the points a,b,c.

I deduced that their angles are $\pi - \frac{\psi}{2}$, $\frac{\phi}{2}$ and $\frac{\psi - \phi}{2}$ respectively.

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are entirely determined on $\psi$ and $\phi$, those latter two are of only interest when determining a,b and C.  With this in mind, define the random variables $\Psi$ and $\Phi$.
Then the tree angles are chracterised by the random variables:
$\pi - \frac{\Psi}{2}$, $\frac{\Phi}{2}$ and $\frac{\Psi - \Phi}{2}$ respectively.
Moreover the assumption of a,b and c's uniformity and independence we may deduce that the random variables are independent with joint density function:
$f_{\Phi, \Psi}(\phi , \psi ) := \frac{1}{2\pi^2}$.  Moreover the realized values of $\Psi$ must bound those of $\Phi$ below.  Therefore the region of interest is the triangle $0 < \psi < \phi <2\pi$ on the $\psi, \phi$ plane (that is in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$).

---

What i've done so far sems right, however i am uncertain how to finish the problem an obtain the probability that one of the three angles will be greater than x$\pi$.

Sorry if this is a trivial question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make blanket statements about the angles like you have done.

To get you started:

Because of the symmetry of the problem we can limit $\phi$ to $0$ to $\pi$.

Consider the cases:

$$\begin{cases}
0\lt\psi\lt\phi, &...(1)\\
\phi\lt\psi\lt\pi, &...(2)\\
\pi\lt\psi\lt\frac{3}{4}\pi, &...(3)\\
\frac{3}{4}\pi\lt\psi\lt2\pi, &...(4)\\
\end{cases}$$

For case 1 the three angles are:

$$\frac{\psi-\phi}{2}$$
$$\pi-\frac{\phi}{2}$$
$$\frac{\psi}{2}$$

and since 
$$0\lt\psi\lt\phi\lt\pi$$ 
it follows that
$$\frac{\psi-\phi}{2}\lt\frac{\psi}{2}\lt\pi-\frac{\phi}{2}$$
So for case 1, we only need to consider $\pi-\frac{\phi}{2}$

For case 2 the three angles are:
$$\frac{\phi-\psi}{2}$$
$$\pi-\frac{\psi}{2}$$
$$\frac{\phi}{2}$$

and since 
$$0\lt\phi\lt\psi\lt\pi$$ 
it follows that
$$\frac{\phi-\psi}{2}\lt\frac{\phi}{2}\lt\pi-\frac{\psi}{2}$$
So for case 2, we only need to consider $\pi-\frac{\psi}{2}$

etc.

Comment: No worries - please post your full answer so that we can all admire it.